# Why isn't "muscle" pronounced "muskle"?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling, latin

It [comes from](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=muscle&searchmode=none) the Latin *musculus* (meaning *mouse*) and Latin has only hard c's.  The "c" has somehow become soft or silent during evolution.  Why did this happen?

Also, if *muscle* is pronounced *mussle*, why isn't *muscular* pronounced *mussular*?

Comment: It's pronounced muskle by Popeye

Comment: It's not? Shiver me timbahs!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are lots of similar examples with a different consonant: "thistle", "bustle", "whistle", "castle", and so on. I suspect that at some point during the history of English, there was a general sound change: -stle → -sle, and -scle → -sle. It just happened that the only moderately common words that ended with -scle were muscle and corpuscle. In neither of them is the "c" currently pronounced.

The reason that the "c" is still pronounced in "muscular" is that this sound change only happened at the end of a word; it's the same reason the "t" is still pronounced in "castellan".

There are also the rare words "crepuscle" (akin to "crepuscular"), which means twilight, and "arbuscle" (found in Johnson's 1795 dictionary), which meant a small tree or shrub. These words are quite rare nowadays, and I can't find a definitive pronunciation for them on the web.

Comment: You (and others in fact) are right; the change occurred in English. I was being very hopeful with the French theory. Indeed, French does have a soft 'c', but requires the cedilla. (Spanish almost always has a soft 'c', or a lisped one.)

Comment: A quick search documents the well-known silent 'c' in '-scle' endings. This probably originated in Middle English or even Early Modern English out of convenience, I'd propose.

Comment: In Shakespeare's time, everybody was still spelling words the way they sounded, so these consonants were presumably in the words in the late 1500s. However, we have from [etymonline:](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=mussel) *The modern spelling [of mussel], distinguishing the word from muscle, first recorded c.1600, not fully established until 1870s. So I'd say the sound change must have taken place somewhere around 1600.

Comment: That sounds about right, yeah.

Comment: Just in case anybody is wondering how to pronounce *crepuscle* or *arbuscle*, the OED says that they are both pronounced with a silent "c". And both these words seem to have come into English in the mid-17th century, so the sound change (that started around 1600) was likely still going on then, probably depending on your dialect. I'd bet the upper classes (those most likely to use *arbuscle* and *crepuscle*) still pronouced the "c" in *muscle*, while by then some of the lower classes had dropped the "c" from both *mussel* and *muscle* (originally the same word).

Comment: Icicle is still in common usage, with a hard c.

Comment: Unless you drop the middle vowel (which isn't common now, and I suspect was not common in the 17th century), "icicle" does not end with "scle".

Comment: How silly - of course it doesn't. Thanks for patience.